# How to use "nmap" to get those IP addresses that respond to a ping?

Tags: networking, ping

On a Ubuntu VM (running on windows) I want to use `nmap` to list all IP's that respond to a ping. I tried

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.200.0/24
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.200.*
```

which incorrectly state for every IP address between  192.168.200.0 and 192.168.200.255 the "Host is up".

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.200.251
Host is up (0.0023s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.200.252
Host is up (0.0021s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.200.253
Host is up (0.00092s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.200.254
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
Nmap scan report for 192.168.200.255
Host is up (0.0012s latency).
```

But that is not true! A ping for e.g. 192.168.200.252 does not respond back.

Also a simple scan like

```
nmap 192.168.200.0/24
```

gives the output

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-01-26 17:08 CET
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 104.73 seconds
```

But when I do

```
ping 192.168.200.10
```

I get

```
PING 192.168.200.10 (192.168.200.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.200.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.67 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.200.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2.71 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.200.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=2.00 ms
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `nmap -sn --unprivileged 192.168.200.*`? Looks kinda like this issue: https://serverfault.com/a/1044822/411612

Comment: Does not work either with `sudo` or without. No host is indicated as 'up' although I can ping `192.168.200.44`. I will write my own python tool. Maybe `nmap` is not suitable to find devices in a network.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is kind of old, but try adding the arguements -vvv -ddd to your ping scan and paste the output please. I am willing to bet that something in the debug output will shed light on whats going on

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1206413)